# Numpy and inverse matrices - method to do only one reshape instruction

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, reshape, matrix-inverse

I am doing a batch execution of high number of 3x3 matrices with CUDA.

The goal is to get a big matrix of 3x3 matrix (so I use a 4D array).

I have done previously the same operation with `numpy.linalg.inv` function. With this way, I can directly get an array of 3x3 matrix : I show you the code that performs this operation.

Now, with CUDA version, I would like to reshape in a minimum of instructions the big 1D array produced : so I have to build a (N,N,3,3) array from a (N*N*3*3) 1D array.

For the moment, I can do this reshape into 2 steps (here the code below).

The original version with classical `numpy.linalg.inv` is carried out by:

```
for r_p in range(N):
  for s_p in range(N):
    # original version (without GPU)
    invCrossMatrix[:,:,r_p,s_p] = np.linalg.inv(arrayFullCross_vec[:,:,r_p,s_p])
```

`invCrossMatrix` represents a (3,3,N,N) array and I get it directly from the  (3,3,N,N) `arrayFullCross` array (`dimBlocks = 3`)

For the moment, when I use GPU batch execution, I start from the 1D array :

```
    # Declaration of inverse cross matrix
    invCrossMatrix_temp = np.zeros((N**2,3,3))

    # Create arrayFullCross_vec array
    arrayFullCross_vec = np.zeros((3,3,N,N))

    # Create arrayFullCross_vec array
    invCrossMatrix_gpu = np.zeros((3*3*(N**2)))

    # Build observables covariance matrix
    arrayFullCross_vec = buildObsCovarianceMatrix3_vec(k_ref, mu_ref, ir)

    ## Performing batch inversion 3x3 :
    invCrossMatrix_gpu = gpuinv3x3(arrayFullCross_vec.flatten('F'),N**2)
 
    ## First reshape
    invCrossMatrix_temp = invCrossMatrix_gpu.reshape(N**2,3,3)
    # Second reshape : don't forget ".T" transpose operator
    invCrossMatrix = (invCrossMatrix_temp.reshape(N,N,3,3)).T
```

**Question 1)** Why the `-F` option into `flatten('F')` is necessary?

If I do only `gpuinv3x3(arrayFullCross_vec.flatten,N**2)`, the code doesn't work. Python is maybe column major like Fortran ?

**Question 2)** Now, I would like to convert the following block:

```
## First reshape
invCrossMatrix_temp = invCrossMatrix_gpu.reshape(N**2,3,3)
# Second reshape : don't forget ".T" transpose operator
invCrossMatrix = (invCrossMatrix_temp.reshape(N,N,3,3)).T
```

into a single reshape instruction. Is it possible?

The issue is about to convert the 1D array `invCrossMatrix_gpu`(N**2 * 3 *3)  directly into a (3,3,N,N) array.

I expect to reshape the original 1D array in one only time since I call these routines a lot of times.

### Update

Is to right to say that array `inVCrossMatrix` defined by:

```
invCrossMatrix = (invCrossMatrix_temp.reshape(N,N,3,3)).T
```

has dimensions (3,3,N,N).

@hpaulj: Is it equivalent to do this?

```
 invCrossMatrix =(invCrossMatrix_temp.reshape(N,N,3,3)).transpose(2,3,0,1)
```

Comment: I can't help with the GPU part. But a couple of `numpy` observations.  `np.linalg.inv` works with a (n,m,k,k) array, inverting the n*m k*2 arrays.  `numpy` is `C`, row major by default, but `xT` is simply `x` interpreted as `F` column major (no data copying).  `reshape` effectively flattens the array first, and then shapes (read its docs).

Comment: `reshape` is a cheap (timewise).  But a 1d array can be reshaped to (N,N,3,3) directly.  Sometimes we use a couple of reshape steps with some sort of transpose between to get the order of elements right.

Comment: @hpaulj . Thanks for your remarks. So is it possible to avoid using `'F'` option for flatten('F') and use a C row major logic before the first reshape, i.e with `invCrossMatrix_temp = invCrossMatrix_gpu.reshape(N**2,3,3)` ? Regards

Comment: If you start with a (3,3,N,N) array, and need to work with a (N,N,3,3), try: ``beta=arr.transpose(2,3,0,1)`.  This will switch the NxN and 3x3 dimensions without changing the order within the dimensions.  This is easiest to verify with an array like: `arr = np.arange(2*3*4*5).reshape(2,3,4,5)`